# PNP B772 Transistor replacement

Tags: transistors, pnp

I have a failure with a PNP Transistor (B772) and i want to replace it with another one, but my supplier does not have it , so what are the PNP transistors that i can use ???

Comment: It would help if you know something about how the transistor is used. A schematic would certainly help. Without knowing its usage, you have to make sure the replacement transistor meets or exceeds every spec, since you don't know which ones the circuit relies on. This makes finding a replacement difficult. Most likely, the circuit only relies on a few of the guaranteed parameters, with others being well above and beyond what the circuit requires. Being able to relax those requirements will make it easier to find a replacement since it opens up many more options.

Comment: That all said, surely the exact transistor is available from the other end of the internet.  So use a different supplier.

Comment: The circuit is a buck converter where is used to step down 9v i dont know the out put voltage since the circuit is not working properly because the B772 died

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can suggest **BD140** which is very popular but be careful, B772 has a maximum collector current of **3A** but BD140 has **1.5A**. So, depends on the usage.

May be you can go for MJE170, 171, 172 or 253.

If you're not satisfied, go to http://www.digikey.com and search for pnp transistors with TO-225 case.

Comment: It shoud be fine since the circuit only max at 1A :) thank you